# Error: object 'ct' not found : in R

Tags: r

When I run this code:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant,id){
    setwd(paste('C:\\User\\Downloads\\R pro\\rprog_data_specdata\\',directory,sep=""))

ct =names(read.csv("001.csv"))
for(i in id){
      print(i)
      f <- paste( gsub(" ", "0", sprintf("%3d",i)),".csv",sep="")
     # data <- read.csv(f)
      print("hello")

      if (!exists("data")){
        data <- read.csv(f, header=TRUE)
        ct = names(data)
      }
     # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
      else{
        temp_dataset <-read.csv(f, header=FALSE)
        names(temp_dataset) = ct 
        data<-rbind(data, temp_dataset)
        #rm(temp_dataset)
      }      
}
print(data)
good <- complete.cases(data)
mean(data[good,pollutant])
}
```

I'm getting:

> Error in rep(xi, length.out = nvar) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'.

But I have used it in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you call `rep`?

This is not your question, but from a performance standpoint growing an object everytime in the loop is not a good idea.
You could try something like:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id) {
    pollutant_data <- lapply(id, function(i) {
        p_file <- paste0(
            'C:\\User\\Downloads\\R pro\\rprog_data_specdata\\',
            gsub(" ", "0", sprintf("%3d",i)),
            ".csv")
        read.csv(p_file, header = TRUE)
    })
    pollutant_data <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, pollutant_data)
    mean( data[ complete.cases(pollutant_data), pollutant] )
    # or use mean(pollutant_data[, pollutant], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `ct` before your loop. What happens here is that `ct` only exists in the scope of your first loop because that's where it is declared.

Comment: I add  `ct =names(read.csv("001.csv"))` code before "for loop" but now  Error in rep(xi, length.out = nvar) :  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'  is coming